# What does it mean K in this sentence? "past my house 4k that way"

Tags: meaning

I'm not English and maybe this question could seem silly to you, but I'm watching a movie and there's this guy explaining how far is a place and he says: "past my house 4K that way"
In this case K doesn't mean kilometers since then the guy then adds: "4 hours walk"
I wonder what K means, thanks in advance for all the answers

Comment: Sure sounds like kilometers to me.  Though I didn't actually hear it -- you did, and you may have misheard.

Comment: Or perhaps "K" = "hours walk".  :-)  If you have the movie title and can find a site with the script, you may be able to find out whether you heard it correctly.

Comment: Perhaps the guy said something like *After you pass my house, **fork** that way* (while gesturing right or left). But it's a bit pointless speculating like this with no link to the original.

Comment: Which country did you hear it in? Kilometres are not used for distance in either the US or the UK, although they are in Canada (apparently) Ireland and Australia. Don't know about other English-speaking countries like NZ and SA. So this info is very relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not see the movie (name of it? if you could). But it appears to me the K is referring to distance.  K is a unofficial shortening of klick .

klick ( a kilometer ) is commonly used by the US military, which uses the metric system almost exclusively in order to facilitate communication with allied forces. (In other English-speaking countries, civilians often say "k" or "k.m." instead.

i have seen Uber drivers use it in texts ... faster to type k than klicks: 'Im ~ 2k fm u".

A klick is the shortened form of the word kilometre or 1000 metres, used verbally. I used the same term when a serving soldier. Interestingly, in conversation people are more likely now to add the abbreviation “kay” (k), as in “We've got another two kays to go.

also 4 k is close to 3 miles. You are correct: walk at 3 mph would only take 1 hour.

my refs:

https://www.quora.com/How-long-is-a-klick-in-the-U-S-military
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/klick

Comment: 4k is close to 2.5 miles. Less than an hour's walk. But maybe the OP misheard the *"four hours walk"*.

Comment: @PeterShor That would depend on terrain, for which no context is given. On a clear path over level ground, a fit adult could walk 7 or 8 kilometers in an hour, but if it's up a mountainside through the bush, 4 km in 4 hours might be reasonable.

Comment: that's my thinking too!!

Comment: @choster: if it took me 4 hours to go 4 km, I would probably not call it "walking". :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm from Australia and if we were to say something was '4K past my house' it would mean four kilometres.

Answer (score -1):

In almost any context involving distance, 4k means 4 kilometres.

The *past my house* part may be relevant - if they live 12k away, or it's very indirect to walk the journey, or they're not very fast over a long walk, four hours *might* not be improbable.